# How do you safely share code that needs an Android Activity?

Tags: android

I want to avoid duplicating code that needs to use methods on Activity (say getActivity().getString()) .

Creating a object that keeps a reference to an Activity does not seem to work (objects are recreated all the time, and any reference to an Activity is null when you need it.)

```
// This won't work, it seems
public class MyUtils {
    public MyUtils(Activity activity) {
      this.activity = activity;
    }
    public String getSomeStuff() {
       return this.activity.getString(R.string.foo);
    }
}

// In a Fragment created by the activity

MyUtils utils = new MyUtils(getActivity());
myUtils.getSomePref();
```

So how to you avoid duplicating code ? 
Is there a "safe" way to factor code that needs an Activity ?
Should you put all the code in the Activity itself, and cast it from Fragments ?

Edit : to clarify my issue, I'm especially looking for a way to share code between Fragments, that are displayed as Tabs in an Activity (using a TabsPagerAdapter).
They all need to access some structured data that is saved as a couple of preferences. 
They also need to access this data in an onSharedPreferencesChanged event handler, when the Fragments are not visible.
In my experience, whenever I stop and resume the application, navigate between fragments, change the preferences, etc... all my variables to the activity are null.

Comment: Why not refreshing the variable each time the activity gets resumed? Fragments support the `onCreate`, `onResume` methods etc.

Comment: also, is that really code duplication?

Comment: Do you have any real-world example besides `getString()`? This is not code duplication really. You'd simply be unnecessarily wrapping the `getActivity().getString()` function with another equally repetitive function.

Comment: Well, in my cases, I use a number of SharedPreferences, and I want to wrap the code that gets stome preferences based on soft-coded Strings. So yes, it's to avoid code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to give the Activity as a parameter to every utility function. (You can even make them static this way.) Also if you don't need Activity specific functions, use Context instead for more generic methods.

```
public class MyUtils {
    public static String getSomeStuff(Context a) {
       return a.getString(R.string.foo);
    }

    // more static utility function here
}
```

Comment: In this case (and a lot of others) it would be better to use Context instead of Activity (Activity extends Context). For example, you have no access to an Activity within a Service, but you can use getApplicationContext() to get a Context and use this function there as well.

Comment: @mus65 good point but you could use `ServiceName.this` or `this` since `Service` also extends `Context`. Which would probably be better in most cases than `getApplcationContext()`. Kupsef, if you change that then you get an upvote from me since I was about to give the same answer but with `Context`

Comment: @codeMagic: `Which would probably be better in most cases than getApplcationContext()` source ?

Comment: @njzk2 Start with [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context/7298955#7298955) and read through the links contained in it

Comment: @njzk2 You're welcome. [This blog post](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/) is hidden in a comment in the previous link but certainly worth reading. Probably should have been edited into his answer.

Answer (score 0):

I usually share my SharedPreferences using a SuperActivity:

```
public class SuperActivity extends Activity {
    protected SharedPreferences prefs;
    public static final String PREFS_FILE = "PreferencesFile";
    public static final String STRING_VALUE_KEY = "StringVal";

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE, 0);
    }

    public String getStringValue() {
        prefs.getString("STRING_VALUE_KEY", "")
    }
}

public class SomeActivity extends SuperActivity {
    ....
}
```

And then you could call:

```
getActivity().getStringValue();
```

from anywhere I would think..